# Setting IPv4 as preferred protocol over IPv6

Tags: linux, ipv6, slackware, getaddrinfo

I'm using both IPv6 and IPv4 in a LAN network containing Slackware 13.0 boxes. How can I set IPv4 as preferred protocol on the workstations in this network? I want to use IPv6 either explicitly or when there are only AAAA records available. For example, if I try to open http://ipv6.org/ from Firefox, I will always connect via IPv6. The situation is the same with other applications. I tried creating /etc/gai.conf and adding the following to it:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

This should control the behavior of getaddrinfo(3) at least in Debian, but it didn't help on Slackware.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing at `/etc/gai.conf`! I was searching forr it for about half a year! :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the man page, inserting a `precedence` value in gai.conf disables the all the other default rules. Try setting all the rules as listed in RFC 3484 (10.3):

```
  Prefix        Precedence Label
  ::1/128               50     0
  ::/0                  40     1
  2002::/16             30     2
  ::/96                 20     3
  ::ffff:0:0/96        100     4
```

Comment: Adding just the last one seems to be enough.  That is `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100`.

Comment: What if the file gai.conf is not present?

Answer (score 1):

ipv6 isn't really my area of expertise, but on the man page for `resolver(5)` there seems to be a few options in `/etc/resolv.conf` that could be related:

> `options inet6` sets  `RES_USE_INET6` in
>   `_res.options`.  This has the effect of trying a AAAA query before an A query
>   inside the `gethostbyname(3)`  function,
>   and of mapping IPv4 responses in IPv6
>   "tunneled form" if no AAAA records are
>   found but  an A record set exists.

Maybe your clients have that option set?